# Sent emails not appearing in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I'm using Outlook 2016 at work, and have got 2 accounts set up: my work one and my Gmail one.

I'm unable to send from Gmail (`"Outlook cannot connect to your outgoing (SMTP) e-mail server"`). I'm not particularly worried about this (I primarily use Gmail's web interface anyway)

If I accidentally try and send an email from my Gmail account in Outlook, then open the email from the Outbox folder, change the "From" dialog box to my work account, then press send, the email is sent, but the email does not appear in my Sent folder for either my work account or my Gmail account. If I don't make this mistake, emails do get saved in my Sent folder as expected.

Is Outlook hiding it somewhere else, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Within Outlook Options tick the `save copies of messages in the sent items folder` checkbox.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it already is ticked. I should have made it clearer that all my normal emails do get saved, the mystery of the missing emails _only_ happens as described in my question